# discord.js saving an attachment "undefined"?

Tags: discord.js

I've had a problem recently with users trolling and then deleting images before I can see what they are.  So I'm creating a log to download everything into a log.  (yes I've instantiated fs.js already).  For some reason though, when writing the file... the file is only 9 bytes big (and the content is just "undefined").  Please help.

```
var attachment = (message.attachments).array();
attachment.forEach(function(attachment) {
  console.log(attachment.url);
  tempName = attachment.url.split("/");
  attachName = tempName[tempName.length-1]
  console.log(attachName);
  fs.writeFileSync(dir + "/" + attachName, attachment.file, (err) => {
      // throws an error, you could also catch it here
      if (err) throw err;

      // success case, the file was saved
      console.log('attachment saved!');

  });
  theLog += '<img src="'+ "attachments/" + message.channel.name + "/" + attachName + '"> \n';
  //theLog += '<img src="'+ attachment.url + '"> \n';
})
```

Comment: What exactly is `theLog`? You are referring to it but never show where it is created or where it is written to a file. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up solving it with a tiny function.  Thanks everyone (especially the guy asking what a variable was... that was super helpful)

```
function downloadAttachment(url, dest, hash){
  console.log('initiating download of '+ url +'...');

  request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(dest));

}
```

the "hash" variable is not used right now.  I was hungry and craving corned beef hash...

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with answering why it saves it as *undefined*.
If you check the docs for [MessageAttachment](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment) `message.attachments.first().file` is undefined. there is `fileName` and `fileSize` but no `file`

To save the file you can do 2 things...

- ### Saving the URLS.

  You can save the url in an array in a JSON file like so:

**JSON FILE**

```
 {
     "images":[]
 }
```

**JS FILE**

```js
    let imgs = require(JSON_FILE)
    imgs.images.push(attachment.url);
    fs.writeFile(JSON_FILE,JSON.stringify(imgs,null,4));
```

### - Saving the IMAGE itself

You can use the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module to pull images from a url

**JS FILE**

```js
    //Start of code
    let request = require(`request`);
    let fs = require(`fs`);
    //Later
        request.get(attachment.url)
            .on('error', console.error)
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`Img-${Date.now()}`));//The "Img-${Date.now}" Guarantees Unique file names.
```

**EDIT:** `request` is deprecated. It's been replaced by `fetch` I can't confirm this code work's with `fetch` but the underlining principle is the same.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try this today.

Comment: Request is deprecated

Comment: @FourCinnamon0 use `fetch` it should work almost exactly like `request`