# how can I download and reupload an image in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I am trying to repost the content from another bot's message while reposting it in the same way except replacing the image with a thumbnail, but when I delete the original message, the bot doesn't have time to get the image and post it itself. Adding a delay is an ok replacement for now, but I don't want the original message to linger. I've heard of Jimp being used to edit images, so how and where would I apply that to this code? I could simply edit the contrast of the image mildy to repost it. Here is the code

```
    if (message.author.id == botid && message.guild.id == guild4) {
      message.embeds.forEach((e) => {
        if (e.title !== undefined && e.title.startsWith("The Dungeon ")) {
          if (e.image) {
            
            let url = e.image.url;
            let desc = e.description;
            request(url, async function(err, res, body) {
              if (err !== null) return;
            
              imghash
                .hash(body)
               .then(async (hash) => {
                  let rareresult = raresdb[hash];
                  //message.delete(e)
                  if (rareresult === undefined) {
                    let result = db[hash];
                    if (result === undefined) {
                      embed
                        .setThumbnail(url)
                        .setDescription(desc)
                      await delay(666);
                      message.delete(e)
                      return message.channel.send(embed)
                    }
```

I am currently using `await delay(666);` to try and alleviate the issue, but I want the `url` to be custom that my bot will be able to post on it's own without worrying about how long the previous message stays up. I hope my question is clear

My issue is which the `e.image.url` or `url` as i've defined it. Simply reposting that `url` as the Thumbnail is not good enough since there isn't enough time for it to load if i delete the original message, so I'm looking to upload my own version of that image and use that for .setThumbnail(url). How do I upload and repost an image in discord.s in the context of this code?

Comment: you are missing a lot of scopes so it's harder to tell when which scope ends, so add the end brackets in

Comment: ok i've added an edit. I don't know if that's what you mean though. the rest of the code is basically doing the same thing under different conditions. like, if rareresult = post it in this way. but its but same pretty much

My issue is which the `e.image.url` or `url` as i've defined it. Simply reposting that url is not good enough since there isn't enough time for it to load if i delete the original message, so I'm looking to either upload my own version of that image and use that for `.setThumbnail(url)`

Comment: You only added one end bracket, If I were to copy the code lock and input it into an IDE, it would give many errors (excluding variable name errors which is fine). There is no end bracket on the `message.author.id == botid && message.guild.id == guild4)` or on `e.title !== undefined && e.title.startsWith("The Dungeon ")`

Comment: but is that necessary for my issue? My issue is about using the `e.image.url` which is the embed's image, and posting it as a thumbnail in my own message, which is `.setThumbnail(url)`. But the problem is that if I don't add a delay, then the image simply doesn't load at all, or it infinitely loads. So I'm looking to see if I can reupload that image on my own somehow and repost my own version of it. I have heard of Jimp being used to edit images and I've seen some code on it but I don't know how to make it apply to this

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you want todo this, you have a few choices. You could *actually **Download*** and re-upload the images. Or you simply save the URL and re-upload using that URL. ([See how to save either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51777869/discord-js-saving-an-attachment-undefined/51792671#51792671))

So then to SEND the image you need to run

```js
message.channel.send({
   files:[{
       attachment: "<buffer or url>"
   }]
});
```

So for example the following code allowed me to send 2 images using both methods:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require("fs");
client.on("ready",() => console.log("Ready"));
client.on("message",function(msg){
    if(msg.content === "sendPhotos"){
        msg.channel.send({
           files:[{
               attachment:fs.readFileSync("./DownVote.png"),
               name:"DownVote.png"
           },{
               attachment: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/679433940615823385/708433102900559933/brave_YnGjgGYqTr.png",
               name:"screenie.png"
           }]
        });
    }
});
client.login("token");
```

The choice of which method is up to you. I recommend however the URL, as this means you won't take up space and have security issues by downloading images.

## Don't use `delay(666)`

Discord.js returns a promise on `message.send` just send the message and THEN delete the original message.

```js
message.send({embed}).then(function(){ originalMessage.delete() });
```

Comment: Thank you for you help but I'm still really confused. The `e.image.url` is something that changes every time something "spawns" so I don't know what to write for an attachment on that. Could you give me an example with my code on how to do it?

Comment: `e.image.url` is just the URL to the image, so you could just have: `message.channel.send({files:[{attachment:   e.image.url   }]});` and it would re-send the image the channel.

Comment: it says ```rm Body
embed.thumbnail.url: Could not interpret "{'files': [{'attachment': 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/720151626588881007/724842359044571186/Spawn.png%27%7D]%7D" as string.```

when i try to do `.setThumbnail([{attachment:   e.image.url   }]})`

Comment: Ah this is because you're using `.setThumbnail` if you check the docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setThumbnail it accepts a string, not an object. so for `.setThumbnail` you just need todo: `.setThumbnail(e.image.url);` You only need the `[{attachment: e.image.url}]` when you're sending a message embed via `message.channel.send({embeds:[]});`

Comment: Thanks again for your help, but my problem is actually that I can't simply reuse the existing e.image.url, because when I go to delete the original message, the image in my own bot no longer loads. So I need a method that will somehow download or edit the original URL and upload a brand new one, using the exact same picture.

Comment: Discord doesn't delete the image after you delete the message containing the image. So the URL is still valid if you get the correct link. Is `e.image.url` undefined? try sending the message before deleting the message. 
HOWEVER if you want to download and reupload the url. See the link at the top of my answer,  I posted how to download images there.

Comment: Well the bot I am making this for uploads a unique URL every time it spawns, it's not a static one from a database or anything. So that is the issue and causes my bot not to load the image of if I delete the original. I read your link but I'm really noob at js and am not sure how to apply it to my code. I got the majority of this code from someone else, and I'm just editing it.

Comment: As I've said before, discord *does not* delete the image, when you delete the message containing the image.  Yes it will be a unique url each time you upload the same image, but it still saves each image, so you can still reference a image you uploaded a while ago if you still have the URL. The bot will load the image if you have the **correct** url. Double check you even are getting a url. Seeing as `msg.embeds` doesn't usually exist unless a bot uploads a embed. I've given everything you need. And I *just* verified my method worked: https://pastebin.com/C1HCec0n

Comment: I don't see a message send/embed delete there though. I wouldn't be asking the question it it weren't happening to me. Without deleting the original bots message, it's perfectly fine and I can repost. Once I delete, it either infinitely loads or doesn't have a thumbnail at all. Certain bots use a static url for their images, where it's always the same and it wouldn't be an issue, but other bots use a dynamic url that is unique every time it's posted, even if it's the same image. For example, that was the case with pokecord, if youve ever played it.

Comment: And to add to that, if I delay, then I can see the image and so can other who are currently there watching. But if I return the next day, log on a different client, reload, etc, the images are gone

Comment: I honestly never had that problem, and I had tested it with my bot a few days ago. I'm currently busy this week so I won't get time to test it with pokecord, but in the mean time you can look at how to actually download the images: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51777869/discord-js-saving-an-attachment-undefined/51792671#51792671

Comment: I will try to figure it out. Probably most of my problem is my lack of experience in js, so I'm having trouble adapting the code to my own

Comment: Thanks again for helping. This seems to be a rare question/issue and your answers have been the only information regarding this